# wpf - designer looks different than application

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles

Hi
I have strange problem. In Visual Studio designer my application looks normal - colors look just like I set them. However if I start an application almost all controls on main window get black backcolor

Here is my xaml code for main window (a bit long)

```
<Window x:Class="SensorNetworkWpf.Window1"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="Diagram Designer"
    Height="850" Width="1251" Background="#200077EF">

<Window.Resources>
    <!--<ContextMenu x:Key="DesignerCanvasContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Paste" Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Paste}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="Resources/Images/Paste.png" Width="16"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Select All" Command="{x:Static s:DesignerCanvas.SelectAll}"/>
    </ContextMenu>-->
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid"  Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="114"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="628*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>





        <!-- Toolbox -->
        <!-- GridSplitter -->

        <!-- Designer -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" >

    <Grid   Height="30" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="btnArrange"  Grid.Column="0"  Content="Rozmieść" Click="btnArrange_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="btnReset" Grid.Column="1"  Content="Reset" Click="btnReset_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="Start" Grid.Column="2"  Content="Start" Click="Start_Click" />

    </Grid>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="pbProgress" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
  </StackPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="Diagram" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,22,0,0">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Canvas x:Name="MyDesigner"  Background="GhostWhite">

                </Canvas>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </GroupBox>


    <GroupBox Header="Algorytm" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,0,0,0" Name="gpAlgorithm" Width="328">
        <StackPanel >
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbSA" Content="Symulowane wyżarzanie" Margin="5,5,0,0" IsChecked="True" Checked="rbSA_Checked"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbSAwT" Content="Symulowane wyżarzanie i trilateracja" Margin="5,5,0,0" Checked="rbSA_Checked" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="MDS" Content="Wielowaymiarowe skalowanie" Margin="5,5,0,0" Checked="rbSA_Checked" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header=" " Margin="346,0,6,0" Name="groupBox1">
        <Grid>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="145*">

                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="371*">

                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="258*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="258*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <GroupBox Header="Temperatura">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="lblStartTemperature"  Content="Startowa:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lblFinishTemperature"  Content="Końcowa:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtStartTemperature" Grid.Column="1"  TextAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtFinishTemperature" Grid.Column="1"  TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>


                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Współczynniki" Grid.Column="1">

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="34.04*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="34.04*"></RowDefinition>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35.93*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="77.57*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="57*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="57*"></ColumnDefinition>

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="lblAlpha"  Content="Alfa:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lblBeta"  Content="Beta:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lblShift" Content="Przesunięcie:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lblRange" Content="Zasięg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtAlpha" Grid.Column="1"  TextAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtBeta" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtShift" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"  TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtRange" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"  TextAlignment="Center" />

                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Sposób rozmieszczenia" Grid.Column="2">
                <StackPanel >
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbUniform" Content="Jednolicie" Margin="5,5,0,0" IsChecked="True" Checked="rbSA_Checked"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbNonUniform" Content="Niejednolicie" Margin="5,5,0,0" Checked="rbSA_Checked" />

                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Węzły" Grid.Column="3">

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="lblAllNodes"  Content="Wszystkie:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lblAnchornodes"  Content="Główne:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtAllNodes" Grid.Column="1"  TextAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtAnchornodes" Grid.Column="1"  TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>


                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>


        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you added any styles/merged dictionaries in app.xaml?

Answer (score 2):

The background of your top level window:

```
 Background="#200077EF"
```

is not showing up in the designer but it is "bleeding through" when you run it because the grid background is transparent.

Update: The real issue seems to be the alpha channel of the background of the window.  In the designer the color "behind" the background appears to be white and at run-time the color "behind" the background appears to be black.  Since the alpha for the window background is not doing anything for you, to make the designer and runtime agree just use a solid window background:

```
Background="#E0EEFD"
```

which is the color equal to 7/8 White + 1/8 #0077EF.